# Javascript Google Maps coordinates, parseFloat 'Coordinate' + Random number error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, random, coordinates

I'm trying to generate a random location for a `Marker` on a google map. I have successfully managed to add the `users latitude` to a random number using parseFloat (when I simply `+` them it didnt work...).

However, I use the exact same code to parse the `users longitude` with a random number, and nothing happens.

E.g:

`Latitude = 49.0291`

`Longitude = -0.9912`

Both of these numbers are added to a number generated by `(Math.floor(Math.random() * 300)/1000)`

The latitude is randomly generated, and the marker moves accordingly. However, when I try to move that same marker vertically, nothing happens (despite the fact that the value does actually change!).

I have attached a [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kd6Uy/) of my code.

All help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of jamming a bunch of code into one line, I split it out and got it to work:

```
var newLat = parseFloat(geoplugin_latitude()) +  Math.floor(Math.random() * 300)/1000.0;
var newLng = parseFloat(geoplugin_longitude()) + Math.floor(Math.random() * 300)/1000.0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UmCNZ/

Nesting functions in code is bad.